# Smallest capacitor in size

Tags: electrical-engineering

What is the smallest capacitor in size, which has been engineered and how much is it's capacitance? I presume it must be something etched on chip.

Comment: There is parasitic capacitance between every pair of conductors.

Comment: etched not itched...

Comment: a) A pair of oppositely charged lithium ions shortly before they collide, and b) not much.

Comment: @wossname not much it's really not an answer.

Comment: That's right, it's a comment.  And for what it's worth this question is very loosely worded, so if you want good quality answers you need to be a lot more verbose in your questions' wording.

Comment: @user6335 go with electrons instead of lithium ions to reduce size further

Answer (score 1):

You can create caps with values down to 10fF or less (that's femto-farads) with size about 1 micron squared, but whether they are useful depends on the amount of stray capacitance in the rest of the chip wiring.